# New laptop, don't know what linux version, cannot start GUI

Tags: linux, acer

so I bought a laptop that has Linux OS and I ave ABSOLUTELY no idea about Linux.
When I start it, it loads some things and then shows black screen with the following text:

```
Acer Linux N1 (1.00.3001)
Kernel 4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64 on an x86_64 (tty1)

Admin Console: https://127.0.0.1:9090/ or https://[::ffff:127.0.0.1]:9090/

localhost login: root (automatic login)
Last login: Sat Jan 14 16:30:25 on tty1
[root@localhost ~]#
```

What should I even write for it to boot into the actual OS, so I can access the files and things? I am stuck here, and I don't know what to do next. I would like to enter boot manager and set boot option to CD, so I can install Windows 7, how do I do that?

Comment: if you cannot press a key during boot to get boot settings, see https://superuser.com/questions/519718/linux-on-uefi-how-to-reboot-to-the-uefi-setup-screen-like-windows-8-can

Comment: Install Ubuntu with a live DVD/USB

Comment: You could take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNebxx5EUqw and similar videos explaining how to install Windows on it.  In any case, this is not a Unix related question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its intent is to install Windows, not to do anything on Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
uname -a
```

This command will print kernel version as well as distribution information.

```
less /etc/issue
```

This file will contain some more detail of the release.

Answer (score 1):

You've actually asked two different questions

> What should I even write for it to boot into the actual OS, so I can access the files and things?

The fact that you have a prompt `[root@localhost ~]#` means that the "actual OS," Linux has successfully booted and you have admin permissions (root). I think you want to start up the GUI. Try entering
`init 5` If you have a window manager and desktop installed, this should reboot the system into GUI mode.

> I would like to enter boot manager and set boot option to CD, so I can
>   install Windows 7, how do I do that?

This answer is not exactly the most technical, but it has always worked for me. Reboot your machine and watch the screen closely. Look for something like "Press ESC (F12, F2, etc.) to enter BIOS setup utility." and do THAT. Once in the BIOS utility, you should be able to find an option like "Set boot order" where you can move CD/DVD to the top of the list. Make sure to save settings before you reboot.
Some system BIOS utilities have the option to set fastboot. If that has been set, you may not see the message telling you which key to press for the BIOS utility. In this case, you have to guess. Reboot the machine, and  while still in the black screen, just mash a bunch of keys. The most likely candidates are ESC, DEL, backspace, or the function keys (F1-F12). If it doesn't work, keep rebooting the machine and try again.
Best of luck.